# Combat strategy for ants

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, complexity-theory

This question refers to the Google-sponsored [AI Challenge](http://aichallenge.org/), a contest that happens every few months and in which the contenders need to submit a bot able to autonomously play a game against other robotic players. The competition that just closed was called "ants" and you can read all its specification [here](http://aichallenge.org/specification.php), if you are interested.

My question is specific to one aspect of *ants*: [combat strategy](http://aichallenge.org/specification_battle.php).

### The problem

Given a grid of discrete coordinates [like a chessboard] and given that each player has a number of ants that at each turn can either:

1. stay still
2. move east / north / west / south,

...an ant will be killed by an enemy ant if an enemy ant in range is surrounded by less (or the same) of its own enemies than the ant [equivalent to: "An ant will kill an enemy ant if an enemy in range is surrounded by more (or the same) enemies than its target"]

A visual example:

[image]

In this case the yellow ants are going to move west, and the orange ant, not being able to move away [blue tiles are blocking] will have two yellow ants "in range" and will die (if the explanation is still not clear, I invite you to visit the [link above](http://aichallenge.org/specification_battle.php) to see more examples and explained scenarios).

### The question

My question is substantially about complexity. I thought to this problem extensively, but I still **couldn't come up with an acceptable way to calculate the optimal set of moves in a reasonable time**. It seems to me that for finding the best possible set of moves for my ants, I should evaluate the outcome for every possible scenario, but since battles can be pretty crowded with ants, this would mean that computation time would grow exponentially (`5^n`, with n being the number of ants involved).

Another limitation of this approach is that the solution being worked on doesn't improve its effectiveness *proportionally* to the time spent computing, **so arbitrarily interrupting its execution might leave you with a non-acceptable solution**.

**I suspect that a good solution might be found via some geometrical considerations** in combination with linear algebra, (maybe calculating some "centres of gravity" for groups of ants?) but I could not pass the level of "intuition" on this...

So, my question really boils down to:

> How should this problem be approached to find [nearly] optimal solutions in a computation time of ~50-100 ms on a modern machine (this figure is derived by the official contest rules)?

If you are interested by the problem and need some inspiration, I highly recommend to watch some of the available [game replays](http://aichallenge.org/games.php).

Comment: I assume you have perfect information (knowledge about the position of all enemy ants). The game is *very* close to Diplomacy (essentially a 2-player-only, upscaled version), so you might want to read up the literature on Diplomacy.

Comment: @thiton - You do have perfect knowledge of the ants that you can interact with. I know Diplomacy very well (actually, I even won a tournament once - the number of players is normally 7, btw! :) ... yet there are key differences between the two that in my opinion make very difficult to transpose the learning from one game to the other... What were you thinking about exactly (I might have missed something)?

Comment: Nothing specific, just the general idea of moving individual pieces concurrently in such a way that you achieve local superiority.

Comment: As you say, it's probably a good idea to keep your ants in a relatively compact group, which you can achieve by calculating the number of friendly ants within a certain radius and using it in your move weighting.

Comment: @biziclop - While you are right about your observation, please note that this question is not about a winning strategy to follow, but how to compute the best set of moves from a given position. In my tinkering around with possible solutions, I did try to assign "a bonus score" to moves bringing the ants closer, but this just affect the scoring... it still doesn't change the fact that I should compute all the possible moves. Additionally, it would be counter-productive for say a situation in which 10 ants of yours have been surrounded by 3 of the opponents: it would preferable to spread out!

Comment: @mac I know, that's why I only wrote it as a comment and not an answer. :) But I still can't see how you got to this `5^n` complexity,

Comment: @biziclop - Each ant has 5 possible moves (N,S,E,W or still). The effect on each move depends of the surrounding environment. Using the image in my question: the orange ant "still" move turns out to be death if any of the yellow ones moves W, but survival if they also stay still or move East. If the map was empty (not blue tiles) I should have calculated all possible moves of orange (5) in relation to any combination of movements of the other two (5 by 5), so the final complexity would have become 5x5x5 = 5^3.

Comment: That's fine in this case but why would you want to multiply this by the possible moves of ants that are a lot further away?

Comment: @biziclop - I don't. In fact I divide the ants on the board in "battle groups" [=all ants that could engage in the same fight in the following turn]. Yet, IRL games, these battle groups can involve dozens of different ants.

Comment: I see. In that case I'd probably go for a limited analysis that assigns an objective to each ant first (attack A, flee from B, move with the group etc.), then use a set of simple rules to turn these objectives into moves without considering what any of the other ants do (apart from avoiding collisions). It's not ideal but it beats having to calculate `5^50` different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT FROM THE OP:**

I'm selecting this answer as accepted as the winner of the contest published a post-mortem analysis of his code, and indeed he followed the approach suggested by the author of this answer. You can read the winner's blog entry [here](http://xathis.com/posts/ai-challenge-2011-ants.html).

---

For these kind of problems, [MinMax algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) with [alpha beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) is usually used. (*) [simple explanation for minmax and alpa beta prunning is at the end, but for more details, the wikipedia page should also be read].

In order to overcome the problem you have mentioned about extremely large number of possible moves, a common improvement is doing the minmax algorithm iteratively. At first you explore all nodes until depth 1, and find the best solution. If you still have some time: explore all nodes until depth 2, and now chose a new more informed best solution, and so on... 

When out of time: gives the best solution you could find, at the last level you explored.

To further improve your solution, you might want to reorder the nodes you develop: for iteration i, sort the nodes in iteration (i-1) [by their heuristical value for each vertex] and explore each possibility according the order. The idea behind it is that you are more likely to prun more vertices, if you first investigate the "best" solutions.

The problem here remains finding a good heuristical function, which evaluates "how good a state is"

(*)The MinMax algorithm is simple: You explore the game tree, and decide what will you do for each state, and what is your oponent is most likely to do for each action. This is done until depth `k`, where k is given to the algorithm.

The alpha beta prunning is an addition to minmax, which tells you "which nodes should not be explored anymore, since any way I am not going to chose them, because I have a better solution"

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to move all ants at once and that the "goodness" of the move of ant A influences the move of ant B and vice versa. So it is perfectly possible for example to have 5 ants and by moving 4 west, those 4 all die. However, by moving the 5th west as well, they suddenly don't die anymore. So I don't see how standard minmax applies here. (Note: I also took part in the contest and have spend many hours thinking of this problem as well.)

Comment: @Darhuuk: an advancement in minmax algorithm in here will NOT be a single move of a single ant, but a complete turn! You might want to use some other AI algorithm [such as hill climbing] to find these states you wish to explore - but certainly, a step in minmax **must** be a complete turn.

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I meant as well :). Hence the problem of minmax here: your first depth alone is already 5^n branches, which is way to big to ever search. And to prune, you'd need some kind of heuristic which takes into account that a losing position could turn into a winning position if `y` other ants move to locations `l1`, `l2`, ..., `ly`. I cant' come up with any heuristic like that, maybe someone can though :).

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem can be solved by turning the problem around. 
Instead of calculating the best moves - per ant - you could caclulate the best move candidates per discrete position on your playing board.

- +1 for a save place
- +2 for a place that results in an enemy dying
- -1 point for a position of certain death

That would scale in a linear way - but have some trade off in not providing best individual movement.

Maybe worth a try :)

Comment: If I understand correctly your proposal, this is the approach I followed for some time but it doesn't change complexity significantly (and surely doesn't bring it down to linearity) while it increases the complexity of the algorithm quite a lot. In fact you have to keep track of the mutual exclusion of certain positions [because they can only be reached by the same ant]. This becomes even more complex when ant 1 can reach A and B, ant 2 B and C, etc... or am I missing something of your proposal?

Comment: Collision can also be factored in by downranking these fields a bit. As far as i can see you would just check the neighborhood of each field and count how many ants may reach it (linear). If multiple ants may reach it you could rank it down ( comparable to the knights tour algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour)

Answer (score 2):

Tricky indeed. You may find some hints in [Bee algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bees_algorithm). This is a set of algorithms to use swarm cooperation and 'reasonable computation time'. Bee algorithms can for instance be used to roughly (!) solve the traveling salesman problem. I expect that these algorithms can provide you with the best solution given computing time.

Of course, the problem can be simplified using geometry: relative positions of ants in a neighbourhood are more important than absolute positions. And also light_303's solution is complementatry to the search pattern I propose.

Comment: +1 for the link... I have to do some reading before being able to see if it is applicable to this case! :)

Comment: it's about strategy. What would you do if you were in control of an army (of ants ;-) Just learned that there also ant colony algorithms exist; these have more to do with routing & scheduling than combat though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms

Answer (score 0):

> My question is substantially about complexity. I thought to this
>   problem extensively, but I still **couldn't come up with an acceptable
>   way to calculate the optimal set of moves in a reasonable time.**

Exactly!

It's an **AI** competition.  AI deals with problems which are too **complex** to be solved with optimal algorithms.

So you have to try "stuff", like your idea about centers of gravity.  Even better would be some genetic algorithms where better strategies are found through natural selection (but it's hard to set up some evolving "framework" for that).

BTW: you can see the [blog](http://www.decompilinglife.com/) of the current leader and his strategy is surprisingly simple.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and in fact I resorted to some kind of heuristics myself... yet, there is a difference (at least in my mind!) between computing a [local] optimum and computing a value that might be acceptable but it's not even a local optimum, just a "statistically appropriate" value (essentially based on a number of assumptions which are applicable in most situations). My question is about the first class of solutions (like the MinMax with alpha-beta pruning suggestion). [I hope I was able to express myself in a comprehensible way...]

Comment: @mac I don't think you can do minmax here.  There are just too many combinations: you have 5^n moves at first depth, and (5^n)^2 at second depth... so you won't get far.  Maybe you could however make some compromise and do partial minmax by not considering all the moves, e.g. by "binding" some ants together, or whatever other kind of pruning.

Comment: @mac A further idea on your center of mass idea: You compute the geometric center of your ants and that of the enemy ants, then you get the line between those centers.  You will want your ants to be on a line perpendicular to that joining line: they attack as a front.  You don't want a "point" in your formation because your ants at the point would be gobbled up.