# fleet combat strategy game AI

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

How can I implement a game AI like the sea battle Ai in [NAPOLEON:total war](http://www.totalwar.com/napoleon/).

I want to finish a small game,which the ship can occupy the island to produce more ships and my fleet can battle with the others. can you give me an example,or what should i learn to finish it. Thank you

Comment: Please describe the scenerio you have. Is your game real time? turn-based? What is your goal? what moves can a ship make in a turn/time unit? How many ships are you expecting to have? ...?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem resembles the **[ants ai challange](http://aichallenge.org/)**. - where each player has a colony, and needs to protect it, gather food, and destroy the oponents colony [not a perfect match to your problem, but similar]

**The winner of this challenge wrote in [his blog](http://xathis.com/posts/ai-challenge-2011-ants.html)** how he did it, so you might want to learn from it. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8574388/572670) also discussed it.

Usually for games, the general approach is to use **[min-max algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)** (recursively check the game tree, assuming both you and your oponent will do the best moves, and chose the one that guarantees you the best result) with [alpha-beta prunning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) (which is an optimization that pruns the game-tree and cuts off states you will definetly not use). 

Since the branch factor might be too high - you might want to use some heuristics in order to evaluate which moves are worth exploring.

Usually the problem when applying this method is deciding:

1. How to chose which move worths investigating? there are many possible solutions for it, one of them is greedy - the ones that were more promising and shallow level are likely to be more promising and deep level as well.
2. Finding a good heuristic function to evaluate the state of the game.

Comment: thank you for your answer~but the ship can approach the target in any direction,while the ant can not~I really want to know how to find the next best move and the tradeoff between conquer the island and fight with the enemy~ you know,the ants ai challenge use the A* for the pathfinding algorithm,but the ship is quite different,I am confused about that~

Comment: @matt: You can still use A* for pathfinding, in here your graph is a grid of tiles, and from each one you can move left/right/up/down - unless there is some obstacle in the way. There are much more possible paths from each direction in here, but the length of the path is expected to be significantly shorter.

Comment: eh~maybe you are right,i think i should think it twice~thank you